# How to check if number is up of multiplication table jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my store, I want to offer a promotion for people who buy up to 1499, 2998, 4497, etc. (it is a multiplication of 1499);

do you recommend me use the conditional if?  use switch? or what do you do in this case?

I ask you this be cause when they buy up to the values (1499,2998, etc) I need to show a div saying that the person won a promotion

I'm thinking do a multiplication of 1499 and check the total of the person is up to  1499,2998 etc, actually a make a multiplication table but I dunno how to check if is between a range

````
var i = 0;

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num*i + "</td></tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");```
````

Answer (score 0):

The table can be there just for display.

```js
const num = 1499;
var i = 0;

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num*i + "</td></tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

To actually calculate the amount won from what the user has bought, divide the amount by 1499 and then call `Math.floor` on it:

```js
const amountWon = input => Math.floor(input / 1499);

console.log(
  amountWon(1498),
  amountWon(1499),
  amountWon(1500),
  amountWon(2997),
  amountWon(2998),
);
```

But make sure to do the calculation on the server-side as well, since none of the code you run on the client side can be trustworthy.